# Rails and `has_many :through`: How to retrieve attributes from "in between" model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have the following models:

```rb
class Physician < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

The appointment has some attributes itself, i.e. "date". How do I retrieve those attributes?

```
physician.patients.each do |patient|
  # How to get the "appointment" model's "date" attribute?
```

The following would work, but it feels a bit like a workaround:

```
physician.appointments.each do |appointment|
  # Now we can access appointment.date, as well as appointment.patient
```

UPDATE

Wouldn't it be great to be able to do this?

```
physician.patients.each do |patient, appointment|
  # ...
```

Comment: If you are trying to get appointment information then `physician.appointments.each do |appointment|` is the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to add a custom method to your patient model

```
#patient.rb

def appointment(id)
   appointments.where(physician_id: id)&.first
end
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
physician.patients.each do |patient|
   patient.appointment(physician.id)&.date #or whatever attribute you want
```